# Modify PHP Eloquent Collection

Tags: php, json, collections, eloquent

I have this JSON data generated with PHP (Eloquent Collection)

```
{
   "1498454460": [
      {
         "value_0": 22.7
      },
      {
         "value_2": 23
      }
   ],
   "1498454640": [
      {
         "value_0": 22.8
      },
      {
         "value_1": 53
      },
      {
         "value_2": 23
      }
   ]
}
```

My goal is getting that data to this format with PHP:

```
{
   "timestamp": 1498454460,
   "value_0": 22.7,
   "value_2": 23
},
{
   "timestamp": 1498454640,
   "value_0": 22.8,
   "value_1": 53,
   "value_2": 23
}
```

My brain is locked so i can't see solution... :/

Comment: You're in Laravel, right? If you have the collection as object, you could use the [flatten helper method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-flatten).

Comment: Laravel yep! Flatten helper doesn't work....i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode the json into array, iterate over the array and create the desired structure like this:

```
<?php
$json = '
{
   "1498454460": [
      {
         "value_0": 22.7
      },
      {
         "value_2": 23
      }
   ],
   "1498454640": [
      {
         "value_0": 22.8
      },
      {
         "value_1": 53
      },
      {
         "value_2": 23
      }
   ]
}';

$result = array();
foreach (json_decode($json, true) as $key => $value) {
    $item = array();
    $item['timestamp'] = $key;
    foreach ($value as $value2) {
        $item = array_merge($item, $value2);
    }
    $result[] = $item;
}

echo json_encode($result);
die();
```